# Failed to start process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled and stuck in a blank screen

Tags: boot, 22.04

I am getting the below error[image: the error when i boot]

After this it leads to a black screen and the pc is stuck there!! Any possible fix? I need to recover my data in the pc too.